# How to calculate the median by fixing some variables?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a data set that I already aggregated. This basically shows the median prices for each cat, root_cat, and cluster on daily basis.

```
date         cluster  root_cat cat median_price
2020-12-07    A          X     1      20
2020-12-07    A          X     2      15
2020-12-07    A          X     2      30
2020-12-08    B          Y     3      24
```

Here is the query that I wrote for calculating the median price.

```
SELECT date,
         page_impressions_cluster,
         root_cat,
         cat,
         MAX(CASE
        WHEN tile2 = 1 THEN
        min_price/100 END) AS median
FROM 
    (SELECT pl.*,
         NTILE(2)
        OVER (PARTITION BY product_id
    ORDER BY  min_price) AS tile2
    FROM pl
    WHERE cluster is NOT null
          AND (date_parse(date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= current_date - interval '15' day) ) d
GROUP BY  1, 2, 3, 4
```

Now, I would like to have one more column that shows the median price for each cat and root_cat last 14 days except the latest day. How can I do this?

Here is the desired output:

```
date         cluster  root_cat cat median_price  median_price_root     median_price_cat
2020-12-07    A          X     1      20                20                    20
2020-12-07    A          X     2      15                20                    22,5
2020-12-07    A          X     2      30                20                    22,5
2020-12-08    B          Y     3      24                24                    24
```

Answer (score 0):

If an approximation of the median is good enough, then you can use

```
SELECT date,
         page_impressions_cluster,
         root_cat,
         cat,
         MAX(CASE
        WHEN tile2 = 1 THEN
        min_price/100 END) AS median,
        approx_percentile(price, 0.5) -- <<== the 0.5 percentile is the median
FROM ...
```

See the doc for the `approc_percentile` function [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html).